# Android WXGA emulator gets distortion in portrait orientation

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing an app for 2.1 and above. First Activity in this app supports only portrait orientation, so I have `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in AndroidManifest file. Activity looks good on almost all screen sizes and SDK versions, except WXGA screen and 4.0.3 SDK (also 3.2). On this screen, there were distortions of the background and buttons.

So I create a new empty Android project for 4.0.3 SDK. Add RelativeLayout and Button in the main.xml and `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` string in the AndroidManifest for main Activity. After debug (WXGA, 4.0.3) I got the same result.

[image: Button distortion in WXGA emulator]

If I change `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to something else, the button looks good.

Same thing with Windows.

**Why this happens? This is emulator problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue, and this occurs with various tablet emulators (eg. 3.0, 3.2, etc.) and only in portrait mode.  It does not occur for the phone versions (eg. before Honeycomb).  Below is the layout file I do a setContentView with resulting in distorted text in the lower right.  It may seem trivial, however, it also distorts ImageViews, Buttons, etc. I also found as I place more views at the bottom of the screen, some of them get clipped, or buttons only partially highlight when pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#888" >

<TextView
    android:text="ABCDEF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />
</FrameLayout>
```