# Android Emulator is (very) distorted

Tags: android, emulation

I guess a picture explains more than 1000 words...

[image]

This is the screen I get after booting - but the boot animation itself is already distorted.
It's possible to interact with the emulator at the elements usual positions - in the screenshot, for example, if I'm clicking in the middle of the lower bar, the home button gets selected.

I had some other AVDs, this is the first one where this behavior occurs.

The `config.ini` for the AVD, running on Windows 7:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
abi.type=x86
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:750a657019b49e621c42ce9a20c2cc30
hw.device.manufacturer=User
hw.device.name=Samsung Tab
hw.gps=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=2048
hw.sdCard=no
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-19\default\x86\
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=601x962
skin.path=601x962
tag.display=Default
tag.id=default
vm.heapSize=32
```

The device is a custom configuration, and I've created [a Gist with my devices.xml](https://gist.github.com/outofrange/f207eeef04a6f3a18410)

I've found [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812587/android-wxga-emulator-gets-distortion-in-portrait-orientation), where the problem seems to be a wrong orientation (upside down) - the answer didn't really help me, and I hope that this bug doesn't exist for three years.

Is this a common problem, and is there some workaround?

Comment: A diagonal like that suggests there is a disagreement (by one pixel?) between the rendering code's opinion of the display width and the displaying code's.  "skin.name=601x962" looks rather suspicious - are you sure about it being 601 and not 600?

Comment: @ChrisStratton We got the resolution from our developers, they said we should test it with 601x962 because of the pixel ratio. The device we are trying to emulate is a Samsung SM-T365.
But another coworker is using the same resolution (he says - haven't checked it yet) without these problems.

Comment: There will be no meaningful difference in pixel ratio using 600 vs 601.  It is possible that a different emulation engine may overlook a mismatch there due to its implementation details - but having built a number of hardware and software systems which create displays, this looks exactly like what happens when you mistakenly add or drop a pixel on each line.  Of course you have to change the skin itself, not just its name.

Comment: @ChrisStratton awesome & thanks a million! Using 600 instead of 601, it's working properly! Could you write an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diagonal display like this tends to be caused by a disagreement (usually by 1 pixel) about the width of the display between the code writing to a linear framebuffer and the code or hardware displaying it.

Your specification of a 601 pixel wide skin is very suspicious. Consider if the width should actually be 600.

Comment: I'm surprised that the emulator (or the dialog to create new device templates) doesn't warn about this.